# PHP file opening error

Tags: php, file, fopen

Ok, so I have looked everywhere for an answer to this question and can not find it. So I have a php file on my godaddy website. The second I add this line of code to it:

```
$myfile = fopen("fileName.txt", "r") or die("Unable to open file!");
```

It prints out this error.

```
Internal Server Error

The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was unable to complete your request.
Please contact the server administrator to inform of the time the error occurred and of anything you might have done that may have caused the error.

More information about this error may be available in the server error log.
```

I have looked through the server error log and found nothing. I have changed the error settings to E_ALL and looked through the logs again and found nothing. I am using Windows plesk hosting on godaddy, and I have changed the checked the boxes for file permissions for write/read/and modify. Nothing seems to work.
Thank you so much for your time, please help!

Comment: Are you sure that the only change you made?  What happens when you comment out the line?

Comment: If I comment out the line the page loads fine. It is the only change I have made sadly

Comment: I highly doubt nothing is being put into your PHP error log. You're probably looking at the wrong file.

Comment: take a look @ the web server error log

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem isn't in the server configuration.
You must change the configuration on the php.ini file. Look fot the allow_url_fopen setting.

Comment: I activated that in godaddys control panel. Do I have to make a php.ini file seperate? Thank you!

Comment: fileName.txt is a URL?

Comment: fileName.txt is just a text document on the server

Comment: If you make changes on the php configuration you also need to restart your server.

Comment: That was intended for @Sergio Vilchis.  It should work exactly like you used it.  It probably has to do with something other then the `fopen`.  You need to find the correct error log.  It should be in the same directory the script is running in.  Sometimes the php file has a BOF marker (beginning of file).  Or Windows may have an issue with EOL characters.  Or the handler for .php is not configured

Comment: So I made a new directory. After rebooting the server. I made two files in it. One php and one .txt. I gave them both every permission godaddy offers. <?php

echo "hello";
$myfile = fopen("/countlog.txt", "r") or die("Unable to open file!");
?>

Comment: Sorry did not mean to enter that, but that was the entire script. When I commented out fopen it worked fine. What am I doing wrong? Did I mess up somewhere?

Comment: If the file is on the server maybe you should access trought http protocol
`$myfile = fopen("http://yourhost/fileName.txt", "r") or die("Unable to open file!");`

Comment: The above comment works^^^ for anyone with future issues if they have them